# Specify custom redirect_uri in a web app that uses Azure AD authentication with oidc and a middleware

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, service-fabric-stateless

I am trying to authenticate an app with Azure AD. It's all good in localhost, it redirects to Azure AD where I enter details to authenticate, and it sends back the token that allows to view the resource.
Everything managed behind the scenes with the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI 3.1.10` in an aspnetcore 3.1 application.

My app runs on http://localhost:5000 and I can configure the redirectUri/replyUri at Azure AD for that application to support this url. All good.

The problem is in a different environment when my app runs in a service fabric cluster.
I can see the problem

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application
```

When I inspect the url I can see that the `redirect_uri` has some url like this `http://12.12.12.12/signin-oidc`

The problem is double here. First of all I don't know which IP the cluster is gonna assign. Second, it is http, not https, and that's not supported by Azure AD.

Luckily my app has an external Url with a reverse proxy I can use to access. Something like `https://myservicefabriccluster.com/MyApp`

That Url I could configure as my `redirect_uri` in both my application and Azure AD, but **I don't know how to do so**.

My code has something like this:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

where I bind my settings.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "76245c66-354e-4a94-b34d-...",
  "TenantId": "59c56bd4-ce18-466a-b515-..."
},
```

I can see the `AzureADOptions` supports some other parameters such as `Domain` (not needed) or `CallbackPath` (which by default is ok being `/signin-oidc`) but there is nothing similar to ReplyUrl or RedirectUri where I can specify an absolute URL as the callback.

I have found a few similar issues without an answer. Others suggest some kind of tricks like a middleware that rewrites that parameter just before redirecting to Azure AD.

Certainly there must be an easier way to deal with this problem that I expect is not so strange. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to overwrite `redirect_uri` parameter with a custom value is to use the Events available in OpenIdConnect library. This library should be available as it's a dependency for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI`, so this is my solution that, in addition to the standard properties for AzureADOptions it adds a flag to determine whether the redirect uri must be overwritten and a value to do so. I hope it's self explanatory

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

var isCustomRedirectUriRequired = configuration.GetValue<bool>("AzureAd:IsCustomRedirectUriRequired");
if (isCustomRedirectUriRequired)
{
    services
        .Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
            AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme,
            options =>
            {
                options.Events =
                    new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctx =>
                        {
                            ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri =
                                configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:CustomRedirectUri");
                            await Task.Yield();
                        }
                    };
            });
}

services
    .AddAuthorization(
        options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                PolicyConstants.DashboardPolicy,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                });
        });
```

And the `appsettings.json` would have something like this:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "76245c66-354e-4a94-b34d-...",
  "TenantId": "59c56bd4-ce18-466a-b515-..."
  "IsCustomRedirectUriRequired": true,
  "CustomRedirectUri": "https://platform-cluster-development01.cubictelecom.com:19008/Scheduler/WebApi/signin-oidc"
},
```

Notice the `IsCustomRedirectUriRequired` and `CustomRedirectUri` are my custom properties that I read explicitly in order to overwrite (or not) the redirect uri query parameter when being redirected to the identity provider (i.e: Azure AD)

Comment: I tried the same approach with `Microsoft.Identity.Web` and it works in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this, you should be configuring the public URL as the redirect URI, which is a value such as this:

- https://myservicefabriccluster.com/MyApp

It looks like that the above library does not easily support this, and forces the redirect URI to be based on the HTTP listening URL of the code. As part of resolving this it is worth considering how you are writing your code:

This line of code indicates that your app is limited to only ever working with Azure AD:

```
- services.AddAzureAD
```

This line of code would ensure that your code works with both AzureAD and any other Authorization Server that meets the Open Id Connect standard:

```
- services.AddOpenIdConnect
```

The latter option also has an Events class with a commonly used [OnRedirectToIdentityProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-5.0) operation that you can use to override the CallbackPath and provide a full RedirectUri.

Azure AD endpoints are standards based so you do not strictly have to use AzureAD specific libraries. Out of interest, I have a [Single Page App Azure code sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/spa/spa.config.json) that uses a neutral library like this, so I know this technique works.

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me to the right direction. The library is not deprecated though. In fact there's a new version for .NET 5.0
But you're right, that library is a bit restricted and I can still use the OpenIdConnect more standard library to access the events. I'll be publishing shortly the solution