# Specify RedirectURI under openidconnect options - Azure AD, .NET6 C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an azure Active Directory and have my app registered under it.
Under the RedirectURIs in the portal, i have specified this http://custom_domain/signin-oidc.

Under my startup.cs, i have these codes.

```
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });
```

All the information specified under the app settings is correct (ClientID, TenantID, etc)

When deployed to my Azure App Service, the redirect URI changes to the app service original url name instead of the custom domain.

> Inspected the login page when my app was executed:
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/5910deee------/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=2782------&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F**WRONG REDIRECT URI WHICH WAS NOT SPECIFIED UNDER THE AZURE PORTAL AD REDIRECT URI**%3A44345%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=6379148910548699......

How can I specify the redirect uri in my codes, or have the MS login page redirect to my custom domain uri? Specifying under the PORTAL -> AD -> Authentication -> Redirect URIs does not work.

Comment: Could you please let me know if in your `appsettigns.json` have you provided the same uri as callbackpath . Check the image for reference  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bo9S.png

Comment: im getting the error "The path in 'value' must start with '/'. " when i follow as per the image you shared. The value is /signin-oidc initially. @AjayKumarGhose-MT

Comment: You need to make sure the redirect url you set in your code has the same value with the value you set in `PORTAL -> AD -> Authentication -> Redirect URIs`. In appsettings.son, you can set the redirect url like @AjayKumarGhose-MT said, or refer to this [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg/appsettings.json). By the way, in azure portal, you can set several redirect urls because one azure ad app can be used by several apps, you may try to remove other urls and just remain the one you set in code.

Comment: `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {
                    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://custom-domain/signin-oidc";
                    return Task.FromResult(0); };
});`
Should set like this?

Comment: In `appsettings.json` file you can provide the `redirect uri` instead of `program.cs`. And make sure that your redirect uri must begin with `https` not `http` . And the correct set in both appsettings.json and portal.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue;

- Make sure that you have provided the `redirect uri` same as on our *Azure AD* *application*(Authentication >..Redirect Uri) in your `appsettings.json` file.

As stated by @*Tinywang*, If you have multiple `redirect uri` in your application please remove those and keep the same which you want to redirect after log-in.

[image]

> i m getting the error "The path in 'value' must start with '/'. " when
> i follow as per the image you shared. The value is /signin-oidc
> initially

So if you have done with all the above steps , Please make sure that your redirect uri must be begin with `https` and not `http` as you have mentioned in the question it is `http://custom_domain/signin-oidc` which is not valid.

For example you can set something like:- `https://contoso.com/abc/response-oidc`.

`Program.cs` should look like this:-

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And in `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[ e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "TenantId": "00000-00000-0000000",
    "ClientId": "11111111-222222-333",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

- NOTE:- *Make sure that you have* ***enabled SSL value to true*** in Visual studio .

For complete setup and more information please refer the below Links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***Supported redirect uri***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#supported-schemes) and [***Configuration file***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#configuration-files).
- **Blog**| [***Create an ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework – Web Forms or MVC) using Azure AD Authentication***](https://blog.matrixpost.net/create-an-asp-net-web-application-net-framework-web-forms-or-mvc-using-azure-ad-authentication/) .
- [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897726/specify-custom-redirect-uri-in-a-web-app-that-uses-azure-ad-authentication-with) suggested by @*diegosasw*

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, everything seems ok in localhost. But when I deploy to my app service it doesn't work.

Comment: After deployment. Inspected the login page when my app was executed: https://login.microsoftonline.com/5910deee------/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=2782------&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F**WRONG REDIRECT URI WHICH WAS NOT SPECIFIED UNDER THE AZURE PORTAL AD REDIRECT URI**%3A44345%2Fsignin-oidc...
The custom domain is created with the SSL binding under the app service. When I go to the website, it brings me to the login page, but the redirectUrl changes to xxx.azurewebsites.net (the default one)

Comment: Could you please make sure that you have configured successfully your custom domain with azure ad proxy ,As i don't have any custom domain to test it. Please refer this [MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-configure-custom-domain).

Comment: And also please refer this: [Redirecting problems and custom domain in App service behind Cloudfront](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/6821/redirecting-problems-and-custom-domain-in-app-serv.html)